# Debugging file handle leaks in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, file, file-io

I'm investigating a problem where it looks like our project is leaking file handles. Our application works for about five minutes but then after a while, low level file opening functions out and out fail. I can make the problem occur even faster if I manually leak file handles.

Our codebase is too complex for me to start manually debugging line by line to see what's going on, so I'm looking for some kind of debugging tool to help investigate this.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using instruments to track any leaks. Any app you build you should really run it through instruments.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652

Hint: profile your app using leaks and you should be able to trace any leaks.

Comment: D'oh. Totally forgot that Instruments existed. Managed to investigate and see that indeed I'm leaking file handles.

Comment: Awesome. It's easy to forget sometimes :). Zombies in instruments is very helpful as well. If you find you click on something and your app crashes for no reason must likely you are referencing a object that doesn't exist. If you setup instruments with zombies it will tell you exactly what message you tried to send to what reference that doesn't exist anymore.